# Dynamic height of two UITableViews embedded in a single view with Auto Layout

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, autolayout, height

I`m trying to adjust the height of two tableviews embedded in a single viewController. .

[This is how it is currently displayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R3YSM.png)

[Current constraints](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TzmD4.png)

If possible, I want to adjust the height of each table to avoid the scrolling effect of the table (it is not possible when the total content of the tables is higher than the screen, in that case the height of each table must be the same )
I have manually changed the constraints to show you what behavior I want

[Expected behavior 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ACWwu.png)

[Expected behavior 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kXWRz.png)

I have no idea what constraints I have to modify and what part has to be programmatically

Answer (score 1):

Here is a scenario:

1. Mapping Data to table.
2. Get tableview's content size
3. Set the constraint = height of the content size
4. Update constraint layout.

In your case, i would like to recommend to use 1 table view with 2 sections. 
Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution would be not using tableView for the first section as its not a complicated content to be displayed on tableView. Even if you want to use tableView, try this.

Take height constraint of the top tableView. Take outlet of the height constraint in your controller. Then just after you are reloading the tableView, assign the contentSize.height to the constraint and call self.view.layoutIfNeeded(). This will change the height of the tableView to be same as content.

You can do same with bottom tableView.